# Create pagination for children of a page in Eleventy

Tags: eleventy

My site has a collection of research reports, which renders out as a page for each report that includes a link to a PDF, like a standard directory based Eleventy collection. For one of the reports, I'd like to add the full report as HTML pages, which each section, e.g. Methodology, as it's own sub page.

In other words, I'd like to have sub pages for a page in a collection.

Could anyone provide advice on how I might do this with Eleventy?

Thanks a million <3

Comment: Omg, I have _exactly_ the same problem! I want to share case studies of my UX and research projects and want to do it in the same way!
Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pagination](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/) like so:

```
---
pagination:
  data: page.subArray
  size: 1
  alias: subData
permalink: "subpage/{{ subdata.title | url }}/index.html"
---

You can then access the data for each sub page via the {{ subData }} alias
```